# How can I access a CollectionType value in my Symfony form theme?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the [symfony-collection plugin](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection/) to manage the CollectionType form types, and it's working perfectly when I create my entities.

But if I want to access some values of my Collection data in my template that update the Entity (like an image, in order to display it), I get this error : `Impossible to access an attribute ("imageName") on a null variable.`

I've managed to dump the form values like `{{ dump(form.vars.value) }}` which returns me the entities of my Collection like this :

```
ArticleAttachment {#3220 ▼
  -id: 6
  -imageFile: null
  -imageName: "59a68c78cca5c_2017-08-24 18.40.39-1.jpg"
  -imageUpdatedAt: DateTime {#5439 ▼
    +"date": "2017-08-30 09:59:20.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
```

But then, if I want the imageName (or any other attribute), like `{{ dump(form.vars.value.imageName) }}`, I get the above error. The rest of the form is fine.

Any clue ?

Here is my form theme:

```
{% block attachment_label %}{% endblock %}

{% block attachment_widget %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ dump(form.vars.value.imageName) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ form_widget(form.imageFile) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.position) }}
            <p class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.imageFile) }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#" class="collection-up btn btn-default" title="Move fruit up"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="collection-down btn btn-default" title="Move fruit down"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#" class="collection-remove btn btn-default" title="Delete fruit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="collection-add btn btn-default" title="Add fruit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#" class="collection-duplicate btn btn-default" title="Duplicate fruit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @sh4 Yes I've dumped form.vars.value as described above.

Comment: Did you tried to access the property using snake_case? form.vars.value.image_name

Comment: Nope, still the same error